# which ssl certificate for exchange

Tags: ssl-certificate, exchange-2007

I want buy a ssl certificate for exchange 2007. I have different choices:
1) protect 1 website
2) protect multiple websites (multiple domain ucc)

Thus I have microsoft exchange on AD domain I think I have to buy the second choice, because the server has 2 different hostname: one is the AD host name (for example srv-mail.myaddomain.local) and one is the internet domain name (for example mailserver.mycompany.com). Is that right  ?

Comment: www.certificatesforexchange.com

Comment: interesting, but why it costs half ? On godaddy it costs more than $100 but here just $59?  why ??

Comment: Different sites charge different amounts.  That's the site I've used for years and thought it could help.  I have no affiliation with them other than using them in the past.

Comment: just and other question, certificatesforexchange.com has not .it tld. I mean it want I pay then I think I can configure the cert, but how can I am sure ?

Comment: Luigi, I don't know the answer to that, you can call them though and talk through your questions before purchasing.

Answer (score 0):

I'll opt for 2) since you might want to cover:

- server host name itself
- AD host name
- mail server name
- maybe different host name for your OWA
- ...

Answer (score 0):

You'll want

- OWA name
- external host name
- internal netbios names for exchange servers
- autodiscover.yourdomain.com (for Outlook clients to autoconfig without errors)

You should include yourdomain.local versions as well if that's something you use internally.